# Problems with MySQLi_query returning boolean

Tags: php

I have searched for similar issues, I can find similar questions. However none seem to answer my question. I am completely new to php and cannot find the reason for my query returning FALSE.
My error:
 mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [Directory] on line 17

My code :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("fdb17.biz.nf","XXXX", "XXXX","2337985_searchengine", "3306");
$testdb=mysqli_select_db($con,"searchengine");
if(isset($_POST['search_query'])){
    $search_query=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($_POST['search_query']));
    echo "<div class=\"searchText\">Search</div><hr/>";
    $search_query_x=explode(" ",$search_query);
    $query="";
    foreach($search_query_x as $search_each){
        if($search_query_x)
            $query="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        else
            $query.="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
    $query="SELECT * FROM search WHERE $query";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $nr=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($nr==0){
        echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search_query</b><br>
    1.Try more general words.<br>
    2.Try different words with similar meaning.<br>
    3.Please check your spelling.<br>";
    }
    else
        {
            echo "$nr results found !<p>";
            while($rr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
                {
                    $title=$rr['title'];
                    $desc=$rr['desc'];
                    $url=$rr['url'];
                    echo"
    <div class='width: 400px;'>
    <div class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></div>
    <div class='desc'>$desc</div>
    <div class='url'>$url</div>
    </div><br>
    ";
                }
        }
}
?>
```

If anyone can spot the issue that would be great.

Updates after first few comments but still getting same issue:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("XXXX","XXXX", "XXXX","XXXX", "XXXX");
$testdb=mysqli_select_db($con,"searchengine");
if(isset($_POST['search_query'])){
$search_query=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($search_each));
echo "<div class=\"searchText\">Search</div><hr/>";
$search_query_x=explode(" ",$search_query);
$query="";
foreach($search_query_x as $search_each){
if($query == '')
$query="keywords LIKE %$search_each%";
else
$query="AND keywords LIKE %$search_each%";
}
$query="SELECT * FROM search WHERE $query";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$nr=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($nr==0){
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search_query</b><br>
1.Try more general words.<br>
2.Try different words with similar meaning.<br>
3.Please check your spelling.<br>";
}
else
{
echo "$nr results found !<p>";
while($rr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title=$rr['title'];
$desc=$rr['desc'];
$url=$rr['url'];
echo"
<div class='width: 400px;'>
<div class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></div>
<div class='desc'>$desc</div>
<div class='url'>$url</div>
</div><br>
";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, most likely the sql query you construct by means of string manipulation does not work. Try dumping it and executing it manually. What happens?

Comment: I hope those aren't actual login credentials. If they are, you better go change them right now. Edit: that was edited out but will still appear in revisions.

Comment: tell me that DB parameters are NOT the real ones ! ('login credentials', thanks to Fred-ii)

Comment: I don't see any leading/trailing spaces in the strings you're appending to your query. That could be a problem.

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_error($con)` say?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($_POST['search_query'])` that could also be an issue here; remove `htmlentities`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The quotes around `'%$search_each%'` will act as delimiters.

Comment: @Barmar oh right, good point.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That could cause the query to not find anything, but it shouldn't cause a MySQL error.

Comment: I'm an idiot, completely forgot, credentials changed.

Comment: @Barmar I know it wouldn't throw an error but as you said, it could cause the query to not find anything.

Comment: `if($search_query_x)` doesn't make sense. `$search_query_x` is the array you're iterating

Comment: @Fred-ii- But in that case `mysqli_query()` won't return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies, I'll do some testing and get back

Comment: `if($search_query_x)` should be `if($query == '')`

Comment: make sure all POST arrays have value also. *Just another 2 cents here*.

Comment: You shouldn't call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on `$_POST['search_query']`. You should call it on `$search_each` in the loop.

Comment: @Barmar I have made the changes you have suggested but getting the same error, I have edited the post to show the edited code underneath. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user7851892 I didn't think that would fix the problem, it was just a recommendation of how to do your code more properly.

Comment: What is the error message from `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: You removed the single quotes from `keywords LIKE %$search_each%`. Those were needed.

Comment: @Barmar Ahah, thanks anyways, this is my first attempt at php code and using databases (if you couldn't tell) and I appreciate any help, its just frustrating that it isn't working.

Comment: Where about in the code should I use mysqli_error?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, got the problem fixed now. I think the main culprit was a case sensitive Mysql table along with a few errors you guys corrected.